# Assume $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. What is the pdf of $X^3$

Tags: self-study, density-function

I have the following that is remaining unanswered and would love some help:

Assume $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. What is the pdf of $X^3$. For a large sample, $n$, what is the variance of the cube of the sample mean over x?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its wiki, then tell us what you've done so far & where you're confused. We'll provide hints to get you unstuck.

Comment: Well, I realize that the pdf is for a normal distribution is generally Google-able. However, how do I account for x^3 and write that out?

Comment: The second part makes little sense to me. How to find the variance (u^3/x)?

Comment: Try [distribution of functions of random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables)

Comment: Both answers posted thus far discuss only the first question asked: "What is the pdf of $X^3?$, which is of little help in answering the other question asked: "What is the variance of the cube of the sample mean?" Let $Y=\left(\sum X_i\right)^3=\left(n\bar{X}\right)^3$. Then, $$E[Y]=E\left[\left(\sum X_i\right)^3\right]=nE[X_1^3]+3n(n-1)E[X_1]E[X_2^2]+n(n-1)(n-2)E[X_1]E[X_2]E[X_3]$$ which can be worked out from the knowledge that $X_i$ are iid $N(\mu,sigma^2)$ and $$E[Y^2]=E\left[\left(\sum_iX_i\right)^6\right]=\cdots$$ from which we can get $\operatorname{var}(Y)=E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: $X^3$ is a monotonically increasing function, so therefore, setting $Y = X^3$, $$f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}(x(y)) \cdot \left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}[x(y)]\right|$$
where $x(y)$ is my notation for "$x$ in terms of $y$."

Comment: So what is the pdf of $X^3$ then?

Answer (score 2):

As Clarinetist said, let $Y=X^3$

then $X=Y^{1/3}$, this is your $ x(y)$  function, which you can replace in

$$ f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}(x(y)) \cdot \left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}[x(y)]\right| $$
$$ f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}(y^{1/3}) \cdot \left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}[y^{1/3}]\right| $$

This is the PDF of $ Y $ or $X^3$; just evaluate the PDF of the normal distribution $ f_{X}(x)$ for $ x=y^{1/3} $, replace it in the above equation and reduce it.

You can find the proof of this and more examples in Casella and Berger. (2002). Statistical inference. p.51.